# How to respond to a JSONP request

Tags: jsonp, vanilla-forums

I'm trying to setup SSO for a vanilla forum, but I'm confused about the JSONP part. I've tried searching here (StackOverflow) and I've been looking at the vanilla SSO docs, but I still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer somewhere else.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['callback'] . "({ \"abc\" : \"xyz\" })";
?>
```